# Myprofile View to layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i need to insert in my layout page the avatar from the photo in base64 of "myprofile". 
I got a sessionmodel connected to the DB.

this is my profile layout to render the img from DB:

```
<div class="row form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BinaryPhoto, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @if (Model.BinaryPhoto != null)
                    {
                        var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.BinaryPhoto);
                        var imgsrc = string.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", base64);
                        <img id="preview_photo" src="@imgsrc" alt="your image" style="height: 100px; width: 100px;" class="img-circle" />
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <img id="preview_photo" src="#" alt="your image" style="display: none; height: 100px; width: 100px;" class="img-circle" />
                    }
                    <input type="file" name="Photo" id="Photo" style="width: 100%;" onchange="loadFile(event)" />
                    @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.BinaryPhoto, null, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "file" } })*@
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BinaryPhoto, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

and this is mycontroller action:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Myprofile()
        {
            var userID = ((SessionModel)Session["SessionModel"]).UserID; // get current user id
            TBL_User item = _context.TBL_User.Find(userID);
            UserModel model = new UserModel();
            model.UserID = userID;
            model.Username = item.Username;
            model.IsActive = true;
            model.Name = item.Name;
            model.BinaryPhoto = item.BinaryPhoto;
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Myprofile(UserModel model, HttpPostedFileBase Photo)
        {
            try
            {
                var userID = ((SessionModel)Session["SessionModel"]).UserID; // get current user id
                TBL_User item = _context.TBL_User.Find(model.UserID);
                _context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified; //UPDATE
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    if (Photo != null && Photo.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        item.BinaryPhoto = new byte[Photo.ContentLength]; // file1 to store image in binary formate  
                        Photo.InputStream.Read(item.BinaryPhoto, 0, Photo.ContentLength);
                    }
                    using (var trans = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
                    {
                        item.Name = model.Name;
                        //item.Email = model.Email;
                        //item.Username = model.Username;
                        //item.IsActive = model.IsActive;
                        //item.SigavUserLogin = model.SigavUserLogin;
                        //item.OperationPlaceID = model.OperationPlaceID;
                        item.LastUpdate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                        item.LastUpdateBy = userID;
                        _context.SaveChanges();
                        trans.Commit();
                    }

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
```

and in my layout principal page i have a small "avatar" in the right side, and i want to put the photo of myprofile in that "avatar".

```
<li class="dropdown dropdown-user dropdown-dark">
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-close-others="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <i class="fa fa-search text-symbol-color-do"></i>
                                <img alt="" class="">
                                <span class="username username-hide-on-mobile text-symbol-color-do"> @sessionModel.Username </span>
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-down text-symbol-color-do"></i>
                            </a>
```

how can i do this ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to photo to be displayed in the layout (which means it has to be visible on all the pages not just on the MyProfile page).

In that case you should use a partial action on the master page which would render the that you have listed in the question.

For example the action can be as following:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult DisplayProfilePicture() {
    var userID = ((SessionModel)Session["SessionModel"]).UserID; // get current user id
            TBL_User item = _context.TBL_User.Find(userID);
            UserModel model = new UserModel();
            model.UserID = userID;
            model.Username = item.Username;
            model.IsActive = true;
            model.Name = item.Name;
            model.BinaryPhoto = item.BinaryPhoto;
            return View(model);
}
```

Then in the cshtml put the following line where you want the image to appear:

```
@Html.Action("DisplayProfilePicture")
```

`DisplayProfilePicture` should be a partial view and should have the logic to render the `img` tag.

Details of the implementation can be found here: https://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx/